# Unexpected msg.sender in onERC721Received

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I have an auction contract with a constructor like following:

```
address payable public beneficiary;
ERC721 nftContract;
bool tokenAdded;
uint256 public tokenId;

constructor() public payable {
    beneficiary = msg.sender;
}
```

I have enabled the contract to receive tokens using `safeTransferFrom`:

```
function onERC721Received(address, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes memory) public virtual override returns (bytes4) {
    require(beneficiary == _from, "Only the beneficiary can transfer the token into the auction.");
    require(tokenAdded == false, "The auction already has a token.");
    
    nftContract = ERC721(msg.sender);
    tokenId = _tokenId;
    tokenAdded = true;
    return this.onERC721Received.selector;
}
```

Following is how I mint tokens:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ERC721.sol";
import "./Counters.sol";

contract MyMintingContract is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function mintToken(address receiver) external returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        _safeMint(receiver, newTokenId);

        return newTokenId;
    }
}
```

The idea is that whomever deploys the auction contract should be the only one that can transfer a token into the auction contract.

The problem is that even though I'm using the same account I've deployed the auction contract with to mint a new token, I get the error `Only the beneficiary can transfer the token into the auction.` from the `onERC721Received` method when I try to use the constructor function to mint and transfer the token to the auction contract.

I wasn't sure if `msg.sender` becomes `MyMintingContract` since it's the immediate one that's calling the `onERC721Received` method, but when I checked Remix, it showed the account that called the `mintToken` to be `from` (which is the same account I've used to deploy the auction contract), which means it should coincide with the `beneficiary` variable.

[image]

If I query the `beneficiary` variable, I get `0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4` which is the same as the address in `from` from the image above. Am I correct in assuming that `msg.sender` is the same as `from`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a given context, `msg.sender` points to immediate parent (caller of current contract) in call-chain, and `tx.origin` points to the root (entry-point) of call-chain.

Consider a call chain:

```
user
  contract A
    contract B
      contract C
```

For context of contract C, `msg.sender` is contract B and `tx.origin` is user.

`from` value in your screenshot is `tx.origin`, but not necessarily `msg.sender` (it's the `msg.sender` of contract A only).

Comment: can I use and refer to `tx.origin` the way `msg.sender` is used within a smart contract, such as in a `revert` modifier?

Comment: Yeah. It is a special global variable. List of all global variables here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties